# how to to put values into array if class is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have a list of values inside a div having class="price" iam intrested to push
values into array if class is present otherwise/ 'not present'.

the div pattern is .mainDiv>span, .price sometime pattern will be .mainDiv > span
sometime .mainDiv > .price

so how to push price value into array if class="price" is present.

DOM tree is below.

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span>
    <div class="price">$2000</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span>
    <div class="price">$300</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span>  <!-- observe here price is not there -->
</div>
```

I am using code like this

```
var arr = [];
$('.mainDiv').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).hasClass('price')){
        arr.splice(i, 0, $(this).text());
    } else {
        arr.splice(i, 0, 'no price');
    }
});
```

Please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you're using `hasClass()` on the `.mainDiv` itself, when the `.price` element is a child. You could use `has()` or `find().length` to get the element.

You could also make this simpler by using `map()` to create your array. Try this:

```
var arr = $('.mainDiv').map(function() {
    return $(this).has('.price') ? $(this).text() : 'no price';
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various issues in your code

1. `$(this).hasClass('price')` - here working of [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method is not as you expected like [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method. It's check the class for the selected element not for it's descentant. So use `$(this).has('.price').length` instead
2. `$(this).text()` - retrives all the div text since you just need the price use `$('.price', this).text()` instead.

---

Use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** method in jQuery for make it optimized.

```js
// iterate aver all div
var arr = $('.mainDiv').map(function(i) {
  // cache the `.price` element
  var $price = $('.price', this);
  // check `.price` element present or not
  // and based on that generate the element
  return $price.length ? $price.text() : 'no price';
  // get the array from the generated jQuery object
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span>
  <div class="price">$2000</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span>
  <div class="price">$300</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>abcdsnndsjdjnd</span> 
  <!-- observe here price is not there -->
</div>
```